# create procedure mysql error near ''

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

My MySQL statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE latest_procedure() BEGIN
DELETE ac.* FROM s_articles_categories AS ac JOIN s_articles AS a ON ac.articleID = a.id WHERE ac.categoryID = 38;
END
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

Any suggestions as to the reason(s) of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `delimiter` and need to close the `end`

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE latest_procedure() BEGIN
DELETE ac.* FROM s_articles_categories AS ac JOIN s_articles AS a ON ac.articleID = a.id WHERE ac.categoryID = 38;
END;//

delimiter ;
```